# Extract value in HTML based on field

Tags: r, dplyr, rvest

I have this HTML example:

```
<d>
    <d>
        <t>0</t>
        <p>1. Question 1</p>
        <d>12111</d>
        <r>
            <o>A. aaa</o>
            <o>B. Sol B</o>
            <o>C. ccc</o>
            <o>D. ddd</o>
            <o>E. eee</o>
        </r>
    </d>
    <d>
        <t>0</t>
        <p>2. Question 2</p>
        <d>11112</d>
        <r>
            <o>A. aaa</o>
            <o>B. bbb</o>
            <o>C. ccc</o>
            <o>D. ddd</o>
            <o>E. Sol E</o>
        </r>
    </d>
    <d>
        <t>0</t>
        <p>3. Question 3</p>
        <d>21111</d>
        <r>
            <o>A. Sol A</o>
            <o>B. bbb</o>
            <o>C. ccc</o>
            <o>D. ddd</o>
            <o>E. eee</o>
        </r>
    </d>
</d>
```

I want to parse it to obtain a table with two columns: **question** and **answer**.

The question is in the p tag: `<p>1. Question 1</p>`.

The answer is defined by the position of the number 2 here: `<d>12111</d>`. So, for question 1, the answer is the second  tag: "B. Sol B".

The output should be:
| Questions | Answers |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1. Question 1    | B. Sol B            |
| 2. Question 2   | E. Sol E            |
| 3. Question 3   | A. Sol A            |

This is what I have tried, but it does not work very good:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(rvest)

pg = read_html('
<d>
    <d>
        <t>0</t>
        <p>1. Question 1</p>
        <d>12111</d>
        <r>
            <o>A. aaa</o>
            <o>B. Sol B</o>
            <o>C. ccc</o>
            <o>D. ddd</o>
            <o>E. eee</o>
        </r>
    </d>
    <d>
        <t>0</t>
        <p>2. Question 2</p>
        <d>11112</d>
        <r>
            <o>A. aaa</o>
            <o>B. bbb</o>
            <o>C. ccc</o>
            <o>D. ddd</o>
            <o>E. Sol E</o>
        </r>
    </d>
    <d>
        <t>0</t>
        <p>3. Question 3</p>
        <d>21111</d>
        <r>
            <o>A. Sol A</o>
            <o>B. bbb</o>
            <o>C. ccc</o>
            <o>D. ddd</o>
            <o>E. eee</o>
        </r>
    </d>
</d>', encoding="UTF-8")

pg2 <- pg %>% html_nodes('d') %>% html_elements('d')

long <- length(pg2)
long_loop <- pg2 %>% html_elements('d') %>% length()

df <- data.frame('questions' = character(long), 'answers' = character(long), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


for( i in 1:long_loop) 
{
  if(i %% 2 == 1)
  {
    pg3 <- pg2 %>% `[[`(1)
    
    pg_question <- pg3 %>% html_elements('p') %>% html_text2()
    pg_soltxt <- pg3 %>% html_elements('d') %>% html_text2()
    pg_solpos <- unlist(gregexpr('2', pg_soltxt))[1]
    pg_answer <- pg3 %>% html_element('r') %>% html_elements("o") %>% html_text2() %>% `[[`(pg_solpos)
    
    
    df[i,1] <- pg_question
    df[i,2] <- pg_answer
  }
}
```

Probably there is a better way to do it with out the loop, using rvest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With rvest plus tidyr, you could try:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)

pg |> 
  html_elements(xpath = ".//d/p|//d/d/d|.//d/r/o") |>
  html_text() |> 
  tibble(text = _ ) |> 
  mutate(questions   = if_else(grepl("Question", text) == TRUE,  text, NA_character_),
         indx_answer = if_else(grepl("^\\d+$", text)   == TRUE,  text, NA_character_),
         answers     = if_else(grepl("Question", text) == FALSE, text, NA_character_)) |> 
  tidyr::fill(questions, indx_answer,  .direction = "down") |>
  filter(!is.na(answers), answers != indx_answer) |>    
  group_by(questions) |> 
  mutate(group_index = row_number(),
        indx_answer = substr(indx_answer, start = group_index, stop = group_index)) |> 
  filter(indx_answer == 2) |> ungroup() |>
  select(questions, answers)

# A tibble: 3 × 2
  questions     answers 
  <chr>         <chr>   
1 1. Question 1 B. Sol B
2 2. Question 2 E. Sol E
3 3. Question 3 A. Sol A
```

Comment: Sorry, but `filter(grepl("Sol", answers))` does not meet the requirement to extract the answer based on the position of the "2" in this part `<d>11112</d>`. The rest is very elegant thank you. I'll need to look into this part `xpath = ".//d/p|.//d/r/o"` in detail to understand it.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to add the numbers in the xpath and add a new "solution number" column in the mutate, so that the `2` can be filtered.

Comment: Hello Hoju.  Try it now, where the filters are done by indexing the position of the key value (ie. "2") within a string based on the position of the row within a group. (I.e. group_by(questions) |> group_index = row_number().

Comment: The xpath ".//d/p|//d/d/d|.//d/r/o" retrieves 3 types of node by their relative position. Each type is separated by a "|".
These correspond to the question title, (.//d/p); the signal that indexes the key character for the right answer (//d/d/d), and the texts of the answers (.//d/r/o).

Answer (score 1):

You could simply create a mask based on the answer key of 2. The initial length of all the 1,2s and the possible answers will be the same and are ordered. You can then filter one by where the value 2 occurs in the other.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

html <- 'your html goes here'

page <- read_html(html)

key <- page |>
  html_elements("p + d") |>
  html_text() |>
  str_split("") |>
  unlist()

answers <- page |>
  html_elements("o") |>
  html_text()

questions <- page |>
  html_elements("p") |>
  html_text()

t <- tibble(
  question = questions,
  answer = answers[key == 2]
)
```